# I am considering changing to Ubuntu from Windows 8.

Tags: windows-8

Will I still be able to use Yahoo mail and Google Chrome if I switch?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Google offers Chrome as a .deb package for Ubuntu and other Debian-based distros. And then there's Chromium by the community. Yahoo mail doesn't depend on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Of course,you have to download google chrome as you did it in windows8.And you'll be also able to use yahoo mail as before.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Mail - sure, that's a website.  As long as your browser can render the HTML and JavaScript that Yahoo spits out, you are good to go. It might be advisable to keep another browser, such as FireFox handy, in case Chromium gets a curve ball from that new Yahoo interface.

As for taking your browsing history and bookmarks and whatnot to Ubuntu, make sure to sign into Google Chrome and synchronize everything.  It shouldn't take more than an hour.  Check it with the Google Dashboard.  Then go to Ubuntu and install Chrome (or Chromium), and sign into it. Shouldn't take more than 30 minutes for all your bookmarks to flow into the computer.  I have successfully changed from Ubuntu 10.10 to Windows XP to Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and back to Ubuntu 13.10 - different computers each time - without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I switched last summer to 12.04, now using 13.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad (originally windows 8).

Provided you change the BIOS to Legacy Support & Other OS, & properly set your connection for the internet, using Google Chrome & accessing Yahoo should not be a problem.

I erred during the first install of 12.04 & no longer have access to any of the windows factory install ... if you are considering a multi-OS boot structure, you need more info than I can provide. (As a side note, the only reason I might need the WFI is if I pass this computer to someone enamored with Windows.)

Comment: Why do you recommend messing with the BIOS setup?

Comment: At least my new desktop computer wouldn't accept anything else but Windows 8 without enabling Legacy Support.